# Fictional "dividend" of accumulating ETFs

Tags: financial-statements, interactive-brokers

A question about accumulating ETFs: is there a way to determine from my Interactive Broker statements how much "fictional" dividend (the money the ETF reinvests from the dividends of each stock they hold) there was for each year? Or is there another way to find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not from your IB statements as that detail is internal to the ETF (the fund is "reinvesting" the dividend, not IB).

You might find it in the reports that the fund provides, or you could look at the non-accumulating version of the same ETF (if there is one) and look at the dividend it pays.

I would note that dividends are not *income* because any stock within the ETF that pays a dividend drops in price by the same amount (there is loads of material online explaining that). So you won't see "jumps" in the ETF price when a dividend is paid by one of its constituents.